# Inviting non-jew in process of conversion for Yom tov?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, yom-tov

Is there a heter for inviting a non-jew in the process of conversion for Yom Tov?

How will they know what a yontiff meal really is, or how to do one, and therefore be able to commit to making their own upon conversion, without having been to any?

Comment: If they can commit to a Shabbat meal they can definitely do a Yom Tov meal. It's even easier.

Comment: That question was asking about inviting non-jews generally, this one is specifically about jews in the process of conversion.

Comment: Actually, that question explicitly says "(eg. for inviting people in the process of conversion)"

Comment: That's exempli gratia, not id est. One of many possible examples, not the specific issue of consideration. The questions are clearly related. But not duplicates.

Comment: I don't see why it's being used as an example diminishes anything. A question that asks "are rabbits kosher on Tuesdays" is definitely a dupe of a question that asks "are rabbit's kosher? like can i have them for dinner tonight".

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that cooking on Yom Tov is only permissible if the food is intended for a Jew. There are ways to invite the non-Jew as an afterthought or "accidentally" make extra.

Some of this is a Fence. My former rabbi (who is more particular than most) held that one could not even revert to Shabbos-mode entertaining lest he forget and do a Yom Tov cooking activity for the non-Jew.

One is allowed, however, to serve only cold food and invite the Non-Jew.

Of course, my ex-rabbi could have been exceedingly stringent on himself (and his congregants) so not only CYLOR, but consult several rabbis to find where the actual issur ends and the fences begin.

Comment: "but consult several rabbis to find where the actual issur ends and the fences begin" Once you ask one Rabbi, you're supposed to follow his ruling.

Comment: How much water do you use for mayim achronim? The mishna berura says to the knuckle (2nd joint not including the one closest to the nail that doesn't bend all the way). There are frum people who just wash their tips and some frum people who actually go back to the kitchen sink. This q is even harder than that. Actually go and find what the halacha is. There are going to be multiple camps so don't let your answer be based on luck of the draw over which rabbi you asked first.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Of course luck of the draw is never the way to go. The way to go is to have a dedicated rabbi so you stay consistent.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Not just supposed to. The Talmud says you are bound to the ruling you received, probably as a Neder. The more rulings your get the more you will get stuck bound to the all the strictest positions. Asking multiple opinions isn't just forbidden, it's ineffective.